# Integrated for loop to calculate values over a grid/mesh

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I am fairly new to python, and I am trying to plot a contour plot of water surface over a 2d mesh.

At the moment the code is running but I am not getting the right solution. I have checked the formula carefully and I am fairly confident that the issue is with my loops. 
I want the code to run for each point on my mesh based on their x and y coordinates. 
The mesh is 100 x 100 resulting in 10000 nodes. I have posted my code below, I believe the problem is with the integrated for loops. Any advice on what I might be able to try would be great.

Apologies for the length of code...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 
import sys
from math import sqrt  
import decimal

t=0
n=5
l=100000
d=100
g=9.81

nx, ny = (100,100)
x5 = np.linspace(-100000,100000,nx)
y5 = np.linspace(-100000,100000,ny)
xv,yv = np.meshgrid(x5,y5)

x = np.arange(-100000,100000,2000)
y = np.arange(-100000,100000,2000)

c=np.arange(len(x))
x2=np.arange(len(x))
y2=np.arange(len(x))
t59=np.arange (1,10001,1)
h=np.arange(len(t59))

om2=1.458*(10**-4.0)
phi=52
phirad=phi*(math.pi/180)
f=om2*math.sin(phirad)



A=(((d+n)**2.0)-(d**2.0))/(((d+n)**2.0)+(d**2.0))
w=(((8*g*d)/(l**2))+(f**2))**0.5
a=((1-(A**2.0))**0.5)/(1-(A*math.cos(w*t)))
b=(((1-(A**2.0))/(1-(A*math.cos(w*t)))**2.0)-1)
l2=l**2.0


for i in range (len(x)):
   for j in range (len(y)):
      h[i]=d*(a-1-((((x[i]**2.0)+(y[j]**2.0))/l2)*b))

h5=np.reshape(h,(100,100))



plt.figure(1)
plt.contourf(x5,y5,h5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Ok apologies I didn't make myself very clear. So I'm hoping to achieve a parabolic basin output with h values varying between roughly -10 and 10. Instead I am getting enormous values and the completely wrong shape. I thought the for loop needed to be more like:

```
for i in range (len(x)):
   for j in range (len(y)):
      h[i][j]=d*(a-1-((((x[i][j]**2.0)+(y[i][j]**2.0))/l2)*b))
```

Is that clearer? Let me know if not.

Comment: `"At the moment the code is running but I am not getting the right solution"` How do you expect us to debug this? Have you confirmed all of your math is correct (`A`, `w`, `a`, and `b`)?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Ok i have edited my post hopefully making the problem clearer.

Comment: and yead i have confirmed the maths is correct, if i manually calculate the for loop for a few values of x and y i get considerably different values to my python output

Comment: `l2` is what exactly?

Comment: l2=l^2 (lowercase L^2) I put it in to simplify the main calculation to minimise risk of errors there.

Comment: You still lack `a` and `b`

Comment: what do you mean you still lack a and b

Comment: your code has not specified them

Comment: @deinonychusaur look above l2

Comment: No, your post does *not* specify them, edit your post so that all variables are explicitly declared and all imports work. Make sure that is the case by opening a new python console and pasting your code.

Comment: ok sorry if im being stupid but i dont understand what you mean by specify.. I was under the impression a=(some value/statement etc) was specifying a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that the complete loop is not necessary.

```
h = d * (a - 1 - (x[None,:]**2 + y[:,None]**2) / 12 * b)
```

Here the magic comes with the `None` in indexing. `x[None, :]` means "`x` as a row vector copied to as many rows as needed and `y[:, None]` means "`y` as a column vector copied to as many columns as needed`.

This might be easiest to understand with an example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(0,50,10)

print x, y, x[None,:] + y[:, None]
```

---

The one-liner above gives:

[image]

Some manual calculations show this should be rather ok.

- *d* = 100
- *a* = 1.05
- *b* = 0.1025

For a corner point at (1e5, 1e5), we have 2e10 in the addition, so the values do not look badly off.

Comment: Thanks thats the shape im looking for so certainly on the righ lines. I was wondering if you could explain what the x[None,:] does? or how it works?